# Converting all math to graphics with TeX4ht

Tags: tex4ht

`TeX4ht` converts all `\(...\)`, `\[...\]`, `$$...$$` and other *math environments* to `png` format. However, it does not convert `$...$` to `png`. It first tries to use `html` codes for `$...$` math, and if it is not possible, then it converts to `png`.

Can I enforce `TeX4ht` to convert ALL math to `png`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Advanced Usage of TeX4ht](http://facweb.knowlton.ohio-state.edu/pviton/support/swphtpa4.html):

> You can convert all inline math to picture format by putting the following commands in a configuration file:
>
> `\Configure{$}{\PicMath}{\EndPicMath}{}`
>
> `\Configure{PicMath}{}{}{}{class=’’math’’; align=’’absmiddle’’}`
>
> Note that, unless you want to make extensive use of TeX fields, there’s no way to do this selectively, so you may find yourself faced with a large increase in the number of images the program generates.